# How necessary are the laws of physics given the impossibility of violating the law of conservation?

Tags: energy-conservation, laws-of-physics

The Damascene theologian Ibn Taymiyya believed that God originates things ex materia, not ex nihilo or without prior material conditions, arguing that this latter type of creation entails a logical contradiction. Although he had an appreciation of the logical necessity of what is now understood to be the laws of motion, I am interested to see the implications of his theological view on the laws of physics in general. Does contradicting any one of the laws of physics (as we understand them) necessitate a conflict with the law of conservation of energy, such that these laws of physics must in fact be necessary if the law of conservation is necessary. I am not asking as to whether or not we may derive any of the laws of physics entirely from the law of conservation of energy, but rather as to what extent the laws of physics can (possibly?) be manipulated without breaking the law of conservation.

Comment: The number of physical laws consistent with conservation of energy are infinite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly break some of the current laws of physics without violating energy conservation. Energy conservation comes from the idea that the laws of physics do not change with time (i.e. what holds today holds yesterday as well). This in turn is a consequence of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Time_invariance).

Noether's theorem permits other symmetries, like the one for conservation of momentum and angular momentum, which are unrelated to time symmetry. So yes, energy conservation is not the be-all-end-all; you can have change other physical laws without breaking it.